# How I show the counter with the part number?

Tags: macros, counters

Here is a MWE:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\newcounter{main}[part]
\newenvironment{Remark}[1][]{\refstepcounter{main}\par\medskip
    \noindent {\underline{\textit\Large{MAIN~:\arabic{part}.\themain}}\\ #1}}{\medskip}


\begin{document}

\part{A}

\begin{Remark}
\label{main:r1}aaa
\end{Remark}

\begin{Remark}
bbb
\end{Remark}

\ref{main:r1}
\end{document}
```

The output is this:
[image]

Now, I want the instead of the `1` at the bottom it will be `1.1` (the main counter and the part).

It should be as a command because I'm using LyX.
It is possible?

Thank you!!

P.S. I know I can do it with other counter (i.e. add new counter). But I wonder if I can do it with only one counter...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have just to redefine `\themain` to be `\arabic{part}.\arabic{main}`. Then in your environment use just `\themain` and no more `\arabic{part}.\arabic{main}`. This way `\ref` command will use `\themain` as redefined and everything will be as you want to. If you want to print just the value of `main` counter use `\arabic{main}` or `\the\value{main}`

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\newcounter{main}[part]
\renewcommand{\themain}{\arabic{part}.\arabic{main}}
\newenvironment{Remark}[1][]{\refstepcounter{main}\par\medskip
    \noindent {\underline{\textit\Large{MAIN~:\themain}}\\ #1}}{\medskip}


\begin{document}

\part{A}

\begin{Remark}
\label{main:r1}aaa
\end{Remark}

\begin{Remark}
bbb
\end{Remark}

\ref{main:r1}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Where I need to put it *exactly*? Because when I put where you say it doesn't change anything... Only if I put it at the end of the preamble it's works. Do you know why?

Comment: You possibly redefine something in your preamble ... or you defined the counter main after `\themain` and this changed back to default ... Check your whole preamble please.